# Is there a way to resolve FORBIDDEN FOR url?

Tags: python, html, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,es;q=0.7','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}

response.raise_for_status()
df = response.json()
```

This used to work but  now this error comes up HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY.

any idea what should i do to access the web site in python ?

Comment: No, this error is quite different and new. I am not able to request this website in python but when I paste the same link in chrome, it works

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case, we should visit the `main` page to obtain the `Cookies` and then contact the `API`:

```py
import requests

params = {
    'symbol': 'BANKNIFTY'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get("https://www.nseindia.com")
        r = req.get(url, params=params).json()
        print(r)


main("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices")
```